# How to test complex methods like this in JUnit?

Tags: java, testing, junit

I have been assigned to test this Java method and I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Can anyone help? This is a `start()` method for a game implementation:

```
public void start() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean continueGame = true;
    while (continueGame) {
        reset();
        play();
        System.out.println("Do you want a rematch?(y/n)");
        continueGame = sc.hasNextBoolean() ;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you have to test it using JUnit? It's possible to do, but not really a suitable assignment unless you are supposed to be learning about redirecting standard input.

Comment: Hey! I can also do System testing, not specifically JUnit. My bad for not clarifying that.

Comment: That would make more sense. What you're testing seems to be essentially the whole of the game, not a "unit".

Comment: Indeed. It's more complicated, this is actually a school project which consists of implementing a board game and with me being new to Java, I'm struggling a little. Could you possibly help with System testing so I can get a little understanding of it? Thanks for the quick answer, by the way.

Comment: It would be better for your class to have a dependency on an `InputStream`, typically via a constructor parameter, which you can mock in a unit test. Then in production code you'd pass `System.in` as the `InputStream` implementation.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer. Could you elaborate this in code by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Look to using assertTrue(res). Use a function to Assign your boolean to the while loop and have the result be true inside of the loop. This way you can use assertTrue(res)

assertTrue is in the JUnit collection

Public boolean isEqual(continueGame){
Logic 
While ()
Return true;
}

Comment: Hello, thank you for your advice. Do I make this function in a separate file or could it be done in the same file as the actual function?

Comment: It would be in the same file. If you did do it in a separate file you would have to use mutators and accessors (getters and setters) and it would probably be really great practice for you.will you post what you have if you still need help lmk I know this stuff is difficult

Comment: I am still interested in seeing what solution you came to, even after this much time has past!